# How to move to a specific div inside a section using fullPage.js after toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

What Im trying to achieve is after I press 'read more..' I want the current active section scroll down to a specific div and move it to the top which has the title 'IM TOGGLE'.

I tried to add this jquery code to move it to specific div:

```
    $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".toggle").offset().top},
    'slow');
```

but it doesnt work. If i add `data-anchor` to the `.toggle` the layout is distorted and it doesnt work. Any suggestion?

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rigz/5odubjsj/10/embedded/

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at the [iscroll.js documentation](http://iscrolljs.com/) which is the vendor library used by fullpage.js when using `scrollOverflow:true` as specified in the fullpage.js docs. 
You might find something that allows you to scroll the scroller.

Answer (score 0):

Add id to the toggle div like so

```
<div class="toggle" id="toggled-content">
```

move down to it by adding href to button like so

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" href="#toggled-content">READ MORE..</button>
```

Comment: i tried to modify my fiddle and it's not working. have you tried using my fiddle?

Comment: Apollogies for late reply i did try edint you fiddle but it seemed not to work. This is a solution that has worked on an old project of mine